# Why does mktime return -1 in Awk?

Tags: shell, unix, awk, mktime

I have file with below data

```
# date format in file is (YYYY MM DD HH MM SS)
 file_create_date       file_execute_date       file_name     
"2017 10 10 12 24 30" , "2017 10 11 09 23 00" , LTE--cNum--T201710110923--W101114450--CHGLSMR01LEMS1--sam--4.0.csv.gz
```

i want output like this

```
 file_create_date       file_execute_date       difference          file_name     
"2017 10 10 12 20 30" , "2017 10 11 13 31 59" ,  "1 Day 01:11:29, "LTE--cNum--T201710110923--W101114450--CHGLSMR01LEMS1--sam--4.0.csv.gz"
```

my script is :

```
awk -F',' '{print $1 "," , $2  , (mktime($2)-mktime($1))/86400 " Day",$3}' Filename
```

But `mktime()` returns `-1`.

Comment: Could you please use code tags for your samples as it is not at all clear from this.

Answer (score 6):

You're passing mktime a string containing double quotes and blank chars at the start and end. Remove those.

```
$ echo '"2017 10 10 12 24 30" , "2017 10 11 09 23 00"'
"2017 10 10 12 24 30" , "2017 10 11 09 23 00"

$ echo '"2017 10 10 12 24 30" , "2017 10 11 09 23 00"' | awk -F',' '{print mktime($1)}'
-1

$ echo '"2017 10 10 12 24 30" , "2017 10 11 09 23 00"' | awk -F',' '{gsub(/\s*"\s*/,""); print mktime($1)}'
1507656270
```